# Can something bad happen when using runBlocking from a coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

From [the documentation of `runBlocking`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) is it clear why it does not make sense to use it from a coroutine, e.g., nest it.

It even explicitly states:

> This function should not be used from a coroutine.

However, it is possible to do so:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runBlocking {
        runBlocking {
            println("hi")
        }
    }
}
```

The (IntelliJ) IDE complains a bit

[image: OCvdVKx]

but the code compiles and runs.

What can happen when done accidentally in a more complex setting? Crashes? Or maybe Deadlocks?

Comment: `runBlocking` spawns new coroutine scope to run suspending code from "regular" code block. What do you want to achieve by nesting them?

Comment: @Pawel I don't want to nest them. :) It's just, I witnessed it in some project (it's already fixed), and I'm interested in learning what could have happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What can happen when done accidentally in a more complex setting? Crashes? Or maybe Deadlocks?

No, nothing like that. In fact, `runBlocking` is specifically written to support nesting:

> If the specified dispatcher is an event loop of another `runBlocking`, then this invocation uses the outer event loop.

The concern you mention is not actually related to nesting `runBlocking` calls, but a general concern of calling any blocking code from a coroutine. We use coroutines with the specific purpose of avoiding to block the thread, so it's usually an error to call blocking functions inside them. You'll get the same warning for `Thread.sleep()`, `java.io` calls etc.